# Consultar dados do Active Directory no Sql Server

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

Eu tenho servicos (WCF) que fazem pesquisas no Active Directory para fornecer dados a diversas aplicações que utilizam Microsoft Membership Provider, e também preciso de algumas dessas informações em algumas queries em um banco de dados Sql Server 2008, gerei uma dll e a registrei no meu servidor Sql, mas estou com um problema de performance dos meus serviços, com o número de usuários aumentando os serviços param com frequência, depois de alguns relatórios observei que o uso de memória aumenta exponencialmente. Gostaria de saber qual a melhor prática para comunicar com o Active Directory, registrar um Dll no Sql Server ou usar OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Directory Services ?

Basicamente tenho uma camada com WCF services onde tenho diversos métodos, GetUserById, GetUserByName, UsersInRole, GetRolesByUser, GetUserGroups, GetUsersInGroup, etc.

No meu banco de dados tenho uma DLL que faz referência a esse serviço, e uso esses métodos como uma função do banco de dados para buscar as informações que preciso e assim filtrar meus dados.

Esse é um sitema de BI, tenho níveis de acesso a informações diferenciados, e toda a segurança é baseada no Active Directory e deve ser gerenciada pela equipe de segurança da informação. A finalidade da minha pergunta é saber se é uma boa prática utilizar essa DLL com as funções no Sql Server, ou se eu deveria fazer as pesquisas LDAP diretamente nas minhas queries dentro do banco de dados.

Comment: Você tem exemplos de código pra colocar no corpo da pergunta?

Comment: Cara, seria complicado mostrar o código porque seria muita coisa, a minha maior preocupação é sobre a melhor prática e melhor performance.

Comment: qual a versão do servidor?

Comment: Usando a conta de administrador local, no windows server 2012, tu pode se conectar no `internal database` (\\.\pipe\MICROSOFT##WID\tsql\query), não sei se encontrarás o que procuras.

Comment: o que tu faz é mais ou menos isso http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/getuserfrmactdircsharp.aspx?display=Print?

Comment: Os servidores são Windows Server 2008, eu não posso acessar com a conta de Adm local, os dados que busco utilizando LDAP no .net. E registro a Dll no Sql Server para poder usar os meus métodos dentro do Sql Server.

Comment: É que sem algum código fica complicado te ajudar.